# Notepad++ change the order of text

Tags: notepad++

consider this as my order of the text  (paragraph followed by image)...

```
<p> this is my first paragraph</p>
<img src="http://xyz/123.jpg />

<p>this is my second paragraph</p>
<img src="http://123/xyz.jpg />

<p>this is my third paragraph</p>
<img src="http://123/xyz.jpg />
```

now  i want to **change the order** of the text using notepad++ like the text below(image followed by paragraph)...

```
<img src="http://xyz/123.jpg />
<p>this is my second paragraph</p>

<img src="http://123/xyz.jpg />
<p>this is my second paragraph</p>

<img src="http://123/xyz.jpg />
<p>this is my third paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using the replace funcion coupled with regular expressions:

Search: `(<p>.*?</p>)(\s+)(<img[^>]+>)`

Replace with: `\3\2\1`

And select "Regular expressions" with the box ". matches newlines" checked.

Comment: what if there are 1000 occurences....???

Comment: Click on "Replace All"? I just did it with 1k orrucrences, it took less than a second to replace them all. Ctrl+H, put the values that I gave and choose the option that I said, and click replace all. 1000 paragraphs/images swapped in less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do it is to just select the line and drag it to above the p-tag. As far as I know, there is no other way to do it simplier.

Answer (score 0):

## One By One:

One by one you can just press `CTRL+T` and that will swap the lines. But only works if it is only one line (one line includes wrapped line).

Do this by placing the cursor anywhere on the line below, and press `CTRL+T` and it will swap it with the line above.

---

## Using a Regular Expression:

If you have 1000 occurrences, then one-by-one isn't practical.

You can also use extended replace using regular expressions but it gets more tricky if the content in between the tags is different between all of then that you need to replace.

in find:

```
(<p>.*?</p>)(\s+)(<img[^>]+>)
```

and replace:

```
\3\2\1
```

make sure "Regular expression" is chosen and "matches newline" is checked.

This regular expression will select all the `<p>` tags and swap with the `<img>` tags.

See below screenshot:

[image]

Now say you wanted to swap a div and a span tag, then you would change the regular expression like this:

```
(<div>.*?</div>)(\s+)(<span>.*?</span>)
```

See screenshot:

[image]

---

## PROOF:

**BEFORE:**

[image]

**AFTER:**

[image]

---

## PROOF of original desired task:

**BEFORE:**

[image]

**AFTER:**

[image]